# Any one help me to solve this i try my best but did not solve this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ItemName    Price   CreatedDateTime  
New Card    50.00   2014-05-26 19:17:09.987  
Recharge    110.00  2014-05-26 19:17:12.427  
Promo       90.00   2014-05-27 16:17:12.427  
Membership  70.00   2014-05-27 16:17:12.427  
New Card    50.00   2014-05-26 19:20:09.987
```

Out Put : Need a query which Sum the sale of Current hour and
sale of item which have maximum sale in that hour in breakdownofSale 
Column.

```
Hour    SaleAmount  BreakDownOfSale  
19      210         Recharge  
16      160         Promo
```

Comment: You may need to take a look at [ask], [tour], [formatting](/help/formatting), etc.

Comment: how you are expecting results  with ItemName

Comment: This is what i want to achieve.

Comment: Current hour means hour of that particular day, right? If yes, then date also should be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
create table #t
(
    ItemName varchar(50),
    Price decimal(18,2),
    CreatedDateTime datetime
);

set dateformat ymd;

insert into #t values('New Card', 50.00, '2014-05-26 19:17:09.987');
insert into #t values('Recharge', 110.00, '2014-05-26 19:17:12.427');
insert into #t values('Promo', 90.00, '2014-05-27 16:17:12.427');
insert into #t values('Membership', 70.00, '2014-05-27 16:17:12.427');
insert into #t values('New Card', 50.00, '2014-05-26 19:20:09.987');

with cte as
(
    select datepart(hh, CreatedDateTime) as [Hour], 
        ItemName,
        Price,
        sum(Price) over (partition by datepart(hh, CreatedDateTime)) SaleAmount,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by datepart(hh, CreatedDateTime) order by Price desc) rn
    from #t
)
select Hour, 
    SaleAmount,
    ItemName
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @James Casey

Answer (score 0):

Though i am not clear with the question, based on your desired output, you may use the query as below.

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR,CreatedDateTime) AS Hour, sum(Price) AS Price, ItemName AS BreakDownOfSale  from TableName WHERE  BY ItemName,DATEPART(HOUR,CreatedDateTime)
```

Replace table name and column name with the actual one.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample query.

You can use SQL Server Windows functions to get the result you need.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    ItemName NVARCHAR(40),
    Price DECIMAL(10,2),
    CreatedDatetime DATETIME
)

-- Fill table.
INSERT INTO @Table
    ( ItemName, Price, CreatedDatetime )
VALUES           
    ( N'New Card'  ,  50.00 ,  '2014-05-26 19:17:09.987'   ),
    ( N'Recharge'  ,  110.00 , '2014-05-26 19:17:12.427' )  ,
    ( N'Promo'     ,  90.00 ,  '2014-05-27 16:17:12.427' ) , 
    ( N'Membership' , 70.00  , '2014-05-27 16:17:12.427' ) , 
    ( N'New Card'  ,  50.00 ,  '2014-05-26 19:20:09.987' )


-- Check record(s).
SELECT * FROM @Table

-- Get record(s) in required way.
;WITH T1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(HOUR, T.CreatedDatetime) AS Hour, 
        CONVERT(DATE, T.CreatedDatetime) AS Date,
        T.ItemName AS BreakDownOfSales, 
        -- Date and hour both will give unique record(s)
        SUM(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE, T.CreatedDatetime), DATEPART(HOUR, CreatedDateTime)) AS SaleAmount, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CONVERT(DATE, T.CreatedDatetime), DATEPART(HOUR, T.CreatedDatetime) ORDER BY T.Price DESC) AS RN
    FROM 
        @Table T
) 
SELECT 
    T1.Date ,
    T1.Hour ,
    T1.SaleAmount,
    T1.BreakDownOfSales 
FROM 
    T1 
WHERE T1. RN = 1
ORDER BY 
    T1.Hour
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this simple solution, Please convert it to SQL Server Query.

This will give you perfect result even if you have multiple date data.

SELECT HOUR(CreatedDateTime), SUM(Price), 
    (SELECT itemname FROM t it WHERE HOUR(ot.CreatedDateTime) = HOUR(it.CreatedDateTime) AND 
        DATE(ot.CreatedDateTime) = DATE(it.CreatedDateTime) 
        GROUP BY itemname
        ORDER BY price DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) g
FROM t ot
GROUP BY HOUR(CreatedDateTime);
```